# How to delay between loop without effect to GUI

Tags: matlab, sleep, matlab-gui

I am working in MATLAB with GUI. And I have a `for` loop and GUI with `while` loop globally, each step I need to delay for about 1 second. But when I use `pause(1)`, the GUI will get stuck and `while` loop is stopped working and did not update until loop finish.
Here is my code:

```
count= uicontrol('Style','text',...
'String', '0',...
'Tag','Count',...
'Fontsize',12,...
'Position',[40, 350,35,35]);
i = 0;
while i < 1000
    %do something
    i++;
    disp(i);
end
```

This is `for` loop in nested function:

```
for m=0:1:10
    %do something
    c = findobj('Tag','Count');
    set(c, 'String', num2str(m));
    pause(1);
end
```

But when I execute this `for` loop, the UI text is not updated. And when finishing, it will display `10` in UI text. I want it will display every step from 1 to 10.
I really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be useful to know *why* you're looping like this - seems like something which should be avoidable using timers or event calbacks.

Comment: Agree with @Wolfie, use a [timer](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html) for your `for` loop, it will remove the need to manually `pause` for 1s.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `drawnow` command. This way you force MATLAB to redraw graphical elements. I am not sure where to put this function into your code, but I would suggest that you try to place it as the last command at first into both loops and then you can figure out where it is important to keep.

I did something similar a while ago with 2 loops, one inside GUI and one in a MATLAB-script. The only way to get both loops running at the same time without blocking was using `drawnow`.

Comment: I have tried the `drawnow` function and it only works for UI updated. I found another way to do is add `while` loop inside of `for` loop then make them work in sequence.